# Android compose navigation issue (screen not showing the second time it is triggered)

Tags: android, navigation

I am implementing an application that uses jetpack compose screens for the navigation. I have 4 screens as part of a bottom navigation bar (which holds 4 bottomNavigationItems). I have one extra screen, that is not part of the bottom navigation bar and it is called TripDetails screen (it presents in a google compose map, the details of the road route that has been recorded by the app).

The user can navigate to the TripDetails screen, from two of the bottomnavigation screens : The mainScreen of the app and the Trips screen (which shows in a LazyColumn all the routes that have been recorded by the app).

The issue i am having, is that the first time the TripDetails Screen is called, by either Main Screen or Trips Screen, it opens and composes correctly. However if the user switches back to the main screen or trip screen and tries to open the TripDetails screen again, the app shows that it tries to open it (the class compose methods get triggered), but the app UI remains black.

Here is how i implement the TripDetails screen navigation:

From the mainScreen :

```
    navController.navigate("tripsDetails/tripID=${lastTrip!!.tripId}")
                                {
//                                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                                    popUpTo(NavRoutes.TripDetails.route)
                                    {
                                        inclusive = true
                                    }
                                    launchSingleTop = false
                                    restoreState = true
                                }
```

and in the navigationHost method, i have this composable:

```
composable(
    route = NavRoutes.TripDetails.route,
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument(name = "tripID")
        {
            type = NavType.IntType
        }
    ))
{
    val tripId = it.arguments?.getInt("tripID")
    TripDetails(mainActivity = mainActivity, testTripsData = ALL_TRIPS_DB[tripId!! -1]!!)
}
```

Any help regarding this bug is appreciated, as i have yet to come to a solution.

Comment: i think seconds time it might not get value for the ```tripId```.

Comment: No, it gets the correct id, as i view it from the debugger.